# Magento 2.3.4 Different hour in REST API

Tags: timezone, magento2, rest

I send request via REST API

```
https://www.mysite.pl/rest/V1/orders/89
```

And have date and time:
"created_at": "2021-09-21 15:59:34",

When I go to Saels->Orders in admin there is different data and time:
"Sep 21, 2021, 5:59:34 PM"

So there is a 2 hours difference. I think this cause a problem with my payment module. In admin timezone is set to CET Warsaw. Why in REST API call there is other time ?

Comment: Is this problem occurs only in REST API? Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue for me by selecting the "Coordinated Universal time" in admin:
Store -> configuration -> General -> General -> Local Options
[image]